# Splitting Database Url into Multiple Domains

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to divide the 2000-3000 link data in PHPMyAdmin database into 5 different Domains, so I am using the following query, but this query helps to update all the links. I want to divide the 2000 data into 5 domains, how can I do it today?

the query i used

```
UPDATE link SET link =change(link, 'https://test.testr10.com/file/images/','https://test1.testr11.com/file/images/');
```

Comment: Do all 3000 domains initially have `test.testr10` before updating?

Comment: yes there is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that all domains have the same `test.testr10` before updating, then it is possible to use the `LIMIT` clause to update in small batches.

Let's say you have 2400 records...

```
-- Set the first 500 records
UPDATE link 
   SET link = 'https://test1.testr11.com/file/images/'
 WHERE link = 'https://test.testr10.com/file/images/'
 LIMIT 500;

-- Set the next 500 records
UPDATE link 
   SET link = 'https://test2.testr12.com/file/images/'
 WHERE link = 'https://test.testr10.com/file/images/'
 LIMIT 500;

-- Run again with 3 in the domain
-- Run again with 4 in the domain

-- Even though only 400 records remain, you can still use 500
-- (only the remaining 400 records will match for update)
UPDATE link 
   SET link = 'https://test5.testr15.com/file/images/'
 WHERE link = 'https://test.testr10.com/file/images/'
 LIMIT 500;
```

Will cover all 2400 records in smaller sets, in 5 queries, based on the example above. Change the LIMIT value to whatever the desired need may be.

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb18b986b983b8b043a5aefdea2d747b) based on the example.